# Forgetful functor from R-modules to abelian groups?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I am trying to see, if the forgetful functor from $\mathbb{Z}[X]$-modules to abelian groups is exact and in case it is not exact, is it left or right exact.

In general, i understand the definition of a functor. In my example the forgetful functor "forgets" the scalar multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, but remembers the addition.

My problems is that i don't know how to apply these definitions to a concrete example.
I tried here with something: ($G$ and $G'$ are abelian groups)

If the forgetful functor is left exact, then we start the sequence with the trivial kernel $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X]\overset{f}{\rightarrow}G\overset{g}{\rightarrow}G'$, here i have to check that $f$ is injective and $im(f)=ker(g)$. 
If it was right exact, we should have $\mathbb{Z}[X]\overset{f}{\rightarrow}G\overset{g}{\rightarrow}G'\rightarrow 0$, where $g$ must be surjective and $im(f)=ker(g)$.

How can we show this formal? Can somene help me with this example, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but your approach doesn't make much sense. Perhaps you should first look at the definition of an exact functor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $R$ is any ring, then the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Mod}(R) \to \mathsf{Ab}$ is exact. Remember that exact := left exact + right exact := preservation of finite limits and finite colimits. In fact, the forgetful functor preserves *all* limits and colimits. The reason is that one really constructs limits and colimits of $R$-modules as the limit and colimits of the underlying abelian groups and endows them with an $R$-module structure. Here is a more concise explanation: Left adjoints preserve colimits, and right adjoints preserve limits. The forgetful functor has a right adjoint mapping an abelian group $A$ to the $R$-module $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,A)$. It has a left adjoint mapping an abelian group $A$ to the $R$-module $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$.

Edit: If you use the definition of exact functors from homological algebra (not general category), i.e. preservation of short exact sequences, notice that a sequence of $R$-modules $A \to B \to C$ is exact iff the image of $A \to B$ is the kernel of $B \to C$, but that these images and kernels are just the ones for the underlying homomorphisms of abelian groups. Thus, $\mathsf{Mod}(R) \to \mathsf{Ab}$ preserves exact sequences.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Martin Brandenburg! Unfortunately, we didn't see anything about limits and colimits, we even haven't mentioned them at all. The only definition of left and right exactness was with the sequence and $im(f)=ker(g)$. Anyway thank you for the answer!

Comment: Yes, ok, but now observe that kernels and images of $R$-modules are just the ones for abelian groups, equipped with $R$-module (sub)structures.