# How do I prove if the forgetful functor is exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, exact-sequence

Hello I have the following problem:

> Check if the forgetful functor from $R$-modules to abelian groups for a ring $R$ is exact or not.

As I understood our case we have the following functor $$F:Mod(R)\rightarrow Ab;~~~(M,0,1,\cdot,+)\mapsto (M,+,0)$$
Which takes as an input an $R$-Module and gives us the corresponding abelian group. But it does not only connect objects from the category, it also connects the morphisms in each category, i.e. we also have $$Hom(M,N)\rightarrow Hom(F(M),F(N));~~f\mapsto f$$
where $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a homomorphism between $R$-modules.

I don't know if everything is correct till now. But then I need to check if it is exact. So we had the following definition:

> Let $R$ be a ring, a sequence of $R$-modules is a collection $(M^i)_{i\in I\subset \Bbb{Z}}$ of $R$-modules together with $R$-module homomorphisms $f^i:M^i\rightarrow M^{i+1}$ where $i,i+1\in I$. Then the sequence is exact if $Im(f^i)=Ker(f^{i+1})$.

But somehow I don't see what sequence I need to take in my case and what this has to do with a functor, I mean I only speak about $R$ modules in the definition of exact and not about functors. It would be very nice if someone could explain it to me a bit.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $R$ is any ring, then the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Mod}(R) \to \mathsf{Ab}$ is exact.

Comment: so but I should prove this? I mean this does not help me much sorry

Comment: The definition of kernel and image of a map $f$ do not change as you move between categories, so if the kernel of $f$ is equal to the image of $g$ originally, then they will also be equal after you use the forgetful functor.

Comment: but what functions to I take for my sequence, so I don't see this. I mean the rest maybe would make sense but I don't see why we consider a functor and where do i "find" this sequence

Comment: I think if you are asked to prove that a functor is exact, but haven’t come by the notion of an exact sequence yet, you might have been asked for something in the wrong order! You can certainly work with the definition of an exact functor before you come across exact sequences, but you might not have a reason to care about them. 

All you need to show is that if you have two morphisms which compose, and the image of the first is equal to the image of the second, then after using the functor you still have that the image of the first is equal to the kernel of the second.

Comment: so do I take a sequence of modules in $Mod(R)$, i.e. $f:M\rightarrow N$ and $g:N\rightarrow S$ where $M,N,S$ are morphisms of $R$ modules. Then I need to show that if this sequence is exact also $F(M)\rightarrow F(N)$ and $F(N)\rightarrow F(S)$ is exact?

Comment: See the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969989/forgetful-functor-from-r-modules-to-abelian-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a proof by Martin.

Comment: @DietrichBurde perfect thanks got it